# React Native - RenderError in WebView

Tags: react-native, webview

I have a problem with the WebView component in React Native (I used Expo XDE). The renderError function appears all the time. Same no problem. The code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://lapommeculturelle.com'}}
        renderError={alert('Erreur', 'Internet non disponible')}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks very much for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than passing a function as a property you are executing alert function every time the component renders. Parenthesis execute the function. Change your code accordingly.

```
<WebView
  source={{uri: 'https://lapommeculturelle.com'}}
  renderError={() => alert('Erreur', 'Internet non disponible')}
/>
```